# How to build project with maven dependencies?

Tags: java, maven-2

I created a maven project with the following structure. For some reason it didn't come with a referenced library.

[image]

I added dependencies to the auto generated pom.xml, along with plugins to create an executable jar file. (Note: this is not the full pom but it contains most of the data info). I had to manually create a Manifest.MF file that contains my main class even though I thought this file was auto generated:

Main-Class: com.sample.MainApp

[image]

This is my main just for testing purpose right now:

[image]

When I call mvn clean package it was able to successfully build a jar file. When I try to execute the program using java -jar name-version.jar, and I come across this error:

If I remove all code related to the dependency jar file I can execute the Sys out. I did research and the reason might that the jar file does not include all the maven dependencies, but I thought that having the jar in the maven dependency should be enough. How can I fix this? Please explain in details. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do some reading on "superjar" or "uberjar" (maybe you should use maven shade plugin). By default your built jar doesn't contain any dependency

Comment: Best is to use the `-jar-with-dependencies.jar` which has been created by maven-assembly-plugin.